# How does one skip a list index out of range error rather than stop the code immediately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Once I compare the center to the elements of the list, I often get a list index out of range error. However, I assumed this meant that the code would simply ignore what was missing and run the code, and it does not. How do I accomplish this?

Here's the code:

```
import random
def cons(lst):
  print(lst)
  smoll = []
  big = []
  a = random.randint(0, len(lst)-1)
  print(a)
  center = lst[a]
  print(center)
  lst.remove(center)
  print(lst)
  for y in range(len(lst) - 1):
    if len(lst) > 0:
      if lst[y] > center:
        big += [lst[y]]
      elif lst[y] < center:
        smoll += [lst[y]]
    lst.remove(lst[y])
  if len(lst) > 0:
    return False
  finaLst = cons(smoll) + [center] + cons(big)
  if finaLst[len(finaLst) - 1] - finaLst[0] == len(finaLst):
    return True
```

Comment: You can handle `IndexError` (and other) exceptions by using `try` & `except`.

Answer (score 0):

your for loop that is generating your IndexError is badly written, I would say that is not the best approach to iterate over a loop while you are removing elements from that list, here is an equivalent code to your for loop block to avoid the IndexError:

```
 for item in lst:
    if item > center:
      big.append(item)
    elif item < center:
      smoll.append(item)

  if len(big) + len(smoll) < len(lst):
    return False
```